# How to add restriction to the jump system?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to recreate I Wanna Be the Guy for my school project.
I want to add a restriction to the gravity system, so the character is limited in air for a few seconds and it jumps again **only when it reaches the ground**. I found many tutorials but mine still not working. (the problem is when you hold W, the character will elevate to the top of the frame, and goes down when the key is released)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("kid");
var playerW = 30;
var playerH = 40;
var playerX = 5 + 40;
var playerY = canvas.height - 40 - playerH + 5;
var right = false;
var left = false;
var up = false;
var rightup = false;
var leftup = false;
var onGround = true;
var dy = 10;
var userchoice = false;
var velocity = 10;

document.addEventListener("keydown", press);
document.addEventListener("keyup", release);

function press(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 68) {
    right = true
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 65) {
    left = true
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 87) {
    up = true;
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 68 && event.keyCode == 87) {
    rightup = true;
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 65 && event.keyCode == 87) {
    leftup = true;
  }

}

function release(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 68) {
    right = false
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 65) {
    left = false
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 87) {
    up = false
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 68 && event.keyCode == 87) {
    rightup = false
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 65 && event.keyCode == 87) {
    leftup = false
  }
}

function Gravity() {
  if (playerY <= canvas.height - 80) {
    playerY += dy;
    playerY += velocity;
    velocity *= 0.9
  }

}


function background() {
  var backgroundX = 40;
  var backgroundY = 40;
  for (var a = 0; a < canvas.width / 40; a++) {
    c.moveTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    c.lineTo(backgroundX, 0); //verticle
    c.moveTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    backgroundX += 40;
    c.lineTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    c.stroke();
  }
  backgroundX = 40;
  for (var a = 0; a < canvas.height / 40; a++) {
    c.moveTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    c.lineTo(0, backgroundY);
    c.moveTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    backgroundY += 40;
    c.lineTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    c.stroke();
  }
  backgroundY = canvas.height - 40;
  for (var a = 0; a < canvas.width / 40; a++) {
    c.moveTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    c.lineTo(backgroundX, canvas.height);
    c.moveTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    backgroundX += 40;
    c.lineTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    c.stroke();
  }
  backgroundX = canvas.width - 40;
  for (var a = 0; a < canvas.height / 40; a++) {
    c.moveTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    c.lineTo(canvas.width, backgroundY);
    c.moveTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    backgroundY -= 40;
    c.lineTo(backgroundX, backgroundY);
    c.stroke();
  }
}


function Player() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.drawImage(img, playerX, playerY, playerW, playerH);
  c.closePath();
}

function Sprites() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo();

  c.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  Player();
  background();
  if (right && playerX < canvas.width - 40 - playerW) {
    playerX += 10
  }
  if (left && playerX > 40) {
    playerX -= 5
  }
  if (up && onGround === false) {
    onGround === true
    if (up && playerY < canvas.height - 40) {
      playerY -= 20
    }
    if (rightup && playerX < canvas.width - 40 - playerW && playerY < canvas.height - 40 - playerH) {
      playerX += 5;
      playerY -= 20
    }
    if (leftup && playerX > 40 && playerY < canvas.height - 40 - playerH) {
      playerX += 5;
      playerY -= 20
    }
  }
  playerY += dy;
  playerY += velocity;
  velocity *= 0.9;
  if (playerY >= canvas.height - 80) {
    onGround = false;
    playerY = canvas.height - 80;
    velocity = 0;

  }
}

var interval = setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```css
body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

h1 {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="kid" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/smash-bros-lelle/images/7/79/The_kid.png/revision/latest?cb=20180424233943">
</div>
```

Comment: `event.keyCode== 68 && event.keyCode==87` is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code don't look right

```
  if(up && onGround===false){
    onGround===true
    if(up && playerY<canvas.height-40){playerY-=20}
    if(rightup && playerX<canvas.width-40-playerW && playerY<canvas.height-40-playerH){playerX+=5; playerY-=20}
    if(leftup && playerX>40 && playerY<canvas.height-40-playerH){playerX+=5; playerY-=20}
  }
```

For starters, onGround===true is a comparison, not an assignment, so this has the effect of a no opp.

Elsewhere, you have

```
  if(event.keyCode== 68 && event.keyCode==87){rightup=true; }
  if(event.keyCode== 65 && event.keyCode==87){leftup=true;}
```

event.keyCode could be 68, 65, or 87. But it can never be 68 and 87. It is one value: The keyCode value of the key

Try those corrections and see if it gets you closer to what you are after

Comment: This should be a comment as you don't provide a solution to OP.

Comment: @TL67TsWvKo great to hear! To mark this answered, please click the check mark next my answer.